# how would I style this rails return statement inline?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, inline

I'm trying to style this return statement inline, but the HTML I enter is just displaying on the page. How would I style this inline?

```
def instruction
if self.o_connection.dongle? 
  return "Plug the #{self.o_cord.name} end of the <div class='greentext'>#{self.o_product.full_name}</div> into the #{self.i_product.full_name}."
```

Answer (score 1):

This method doesn't seem to be in a Helper (it probably should be). Regardless, you can use `html_safe`.

```
def instruction
  if self.o_connection.dongle? 
    return "Plug the #{self.o_cord.name} end of the <div class='greentext'>#{self.o_product.full_name}</div> into the #{self.i_product.full_name}.".html_safe
```

The alternative is to do something like this in your View:

```
<%= raw(object.instruction) %>
```

In either case - I would be mindful of any security risks. Take a look at [Sanitize Helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-sanitize).

Answer (score 0):

return a variable with the string and in the view display it raw like this:

```
<%=raw(variable)%>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the style attribute to add inline styles:

```
{ :style => 'display: block;' }
```